# ¿Existe una alternativa a kbhit y getch?

Tags: c++, kbhit, getch

He visto en algunas partes, que, supuestamente las funciones: getch y kbhit son una mala práctica.
Creo que lo dicen por la compatibilidad de las plataformas...

¿Existe alguna alternativa a esas 2 funciones? Si es así, ¿Cuáles serían?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que son especificas para cada plataforma. Y el comportamiento que te ofrecen no es uno que sea estandar de c++ ni de c. Entonces no exste una alternativa portable para usarlas, si quieres su funcionalidad vas a tener que cambiar el codigo dependiendo de la plataforma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... que las funciones: getch y kbhit son una mala práctica.

## NO

Son funciones **exclusivas de una plataforma**, que es una cosa distinta.

Al ser funciones dependientes de la plataforma, puede que en otras plataformas **no estén disponibles o funcionen de otra manera**.

El único inconveniente que tienen **todas** las funciones no estándar es precisamente ese, que no son comunes. Por lo tanto, antes de *portar* tu código a otra plataforma, tendrás que investigar y hacer pruebas hasta que compruebes que funciona exactamente como esperas. Tal vez no te compense el ahorro de tiempo inicial por las modificaciones necesarias durante el proceso de *portabilidad* a otra plataforma distinta.

A otro nivel, estás diciendo que no se puede usar `IPhone` porque no es `Android`, o que no se puede usar `Android` porque no es `IPhone`. Las aplicaciones de uno no funcionan en el otro. Lo cual te lleva a duplicar el trabajo.
Pues lo mismo. Si no buscas un código portable, sino adaptado a la plataforma, no tienen mayor inconveniente.

Piensa que es **virtualmente imposible** realizar código *no-trivial* sin usar funciones exclusivas de la plataforma:

1. En POSIX, existe la función [`mmap( )`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap).
2. En Windows, exiten la funciones de [*file mapping*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping).

- El estándar C++ **no proporciona** ninguna función de mapeo de archivos.

El uso tanto de `1` como de `2` proporciona unas funcionalidades que **yo** necesito en mi código.

¿ Porqué no voy a usar `1` o `2` ? Siempre y cuando que, claramente, no espere que mi código funcione 100% portable entre ambas plataformas :-)

> ¿Existe alguna alternativa a esas 2 funciones?

Y yo añado ... ¿ Portable ? Pues no. Cada plataforma tendrá algo mas o menos equivalente. ¿ Para consola ? ¿ Para Interfaz Gráfica ? ¿ Gtk ? ¿ Qt ? ¿ XWindow *a pelo* ? ¿ Para consola *raw* ? Depende :-)

Comment: Yo quiero que mi aplicación sea de consola, aunque por ahora, no quiero que mi aplicación sea multiplataforma. He visto una librería llamada: [Ncurses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses#:~:text=Ncurses%20es%20una%20biblioteca%20de,interfaces%20basadas%20en%20texto%2C%20TUIs.), pero no sé como descargarla; busco tutoriales y nada; busco por la página oficial y nada... También tengo una pregunta: ¿Ncurses funciona para Windows 10?

Comment: Pues no buscas bien, porque en [su página oficial](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) lo tienes todo :-) Se descarga como código fuente y se compila en local. Indica que es compilable usado `minGW` en Win32 (probado en Windows 7). No te puedo decir mas porque no la uso.